# How to explicitly set database engine when using to_sql() in pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

How could I possibly patch the sql statement in the pandas to_sql() function, so the newly created table uses the MYISAM storage engine?

I need MYISAM because of a very large amount of columns. This currently causes issues with the standard database engine INNODB (Row size too large (> 8126).

I am aware that it is possible to set the database engine explicitly in a mysql statement upon table creation. Perhaps it's possible to patch the sql that is generated by the to_sql() function?

> To specify explicitly that you want a MyISAM table, indicate that with an ENGINE table option: CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = MYISAM;

This is how I create the table currently

```
df.to_sql(con=engine, name="generated_" + reportConfiguration.shortName + "_" + reportConfiguration.marketplace, if_exists='replace',index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge, *storage engine* of *MySQL* can't be set using `df.to_sql` or `engine = create_engine('mysql+pymy....://x@y/z')`.

MySQL storage engine can be added to table structure once it is created.
`executing` an `alter table` command over the `engine` connection, you can modify the table storage engine.

**Example**:

```
with engine.begin() as conn:     
      conn.execute("ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = MYISAM")
```

**Documentation**:

- [***Working with Engines and Connections***](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html)

  - [execute(object, *multiparams, **params)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute)
  - Executes a SQL statement construct and returns a ResultProxy